# Determine if class of given name exists

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This may be a silly question but I've searched around and found nothing.

I have a code:

```
class A {}

let className = 'A';
```

I need to check if `className` corresponds to an existing class.

This is all not in the global scope and is running in node.js so I can't use `window`

I know that the following would work:

```
eval(`typeof ${className} === 'function'`);
```

However I am a bit reluctant to use `eval` (and also the linter complains about it)

In addition I need to also instantiate the class as a variable which again I can do with eval like so:

```
 let ctor = eval(className);
 let object = new ctor();
```

But again this uses eval.

Is there any alternative way to achieve these?

Comment: Is the class is not in global scope? Is this class a private member of another class or scope?

Comment: @gurvinder372 this is not in the global scope, it's in a module

Comment: If it is not exposed from that module, then how do you plan to reach it at first place?

Comment: @gurvinder372 I might have misunderstood your initial point. Yes it's in a module but so is the code to check if the string is a class visible within that module

Comment: If not eval, then you can use `Function` constructor which won't immediately evaluate the function body.

Comment: I guess the question should explicitly state that it's about Node.js . It will be totally different in browser, primarily because of minification, not just `window`.

Comment: @estus it is stated, though not really emphasised

Comment: Is there a reason you need to check the current scope as a whole? You could for instance do `const availableClasses = { A };` and check `className in availableClasses` (or expand to handle own properties specifically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Function` constructor

```
function ac(){} //new class
var f = new Function( "return typeof ac == 'function'" ) //define function to verify
f(); //returns true if class exists in the current scope
```

Make it more generic

```
function ac(){} //new class
var f = function( className ){
  return new Function( "return typeof " + className + " == 'function'" )(); //define function to verify and invoke the same
} 
f( "ac" ); //returns true if class exists in the current scope
```

Comment: Well, this is technically not `eval` but it also is `eval` What I am getting from this is that using some sort of `eval` seems unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

This may indicate indicate wrong design decision and possible XY problem. The need for `eval` usually indicates this. It's developer's responsibility to keep track of classes in use.

If functions are exported, `module.exports` can be checked. If they are not exported, they likely should be.

If classes should be tracked more than in a single module, a container can be used, and the functions should be registered explicitly:

```
const globalClassContainer = new Map;
function registerClass(cls) {
  if (globalClassContainer.has(cls.name))
    globalClassContainer.set(cls.name, new Set);

  globalClassContainer.get(cls.name).add(cls);
}

class Foo {};
registerClass(Foo);
```

Functions are not supposed to be unequivocally identified by their names, names are supposed to be used only for debugging purposes. There can be more than one function with same `name` (even within current scope), there can be functions that don't match `name`. Function `name` tends to be safer in Node.js, but there's no guarantee for safety:

```
class Foo {}
const Bar = Foo; // Bar.name === 'Foo';

const bazFactory = () => class {};
const Baz = bazFactory(); // Baz.name === '';
```