# ES6 class instance from string

Tags: javascript, string, instance, es6-class

I try to setup an instance dynamically from a string. I've read many questions about it but the answers does not work for me.

It says it's possible to use `window` before the name to set the instance. It does not work.

```js
class MyClass {
  // Something useful
}
```

```js
let params = {};
let name = 'MyClass';
let instance = new window[name](params);
```

I've also tried to do this without luck (throws error):

```js
let instance = new window['MyClass'](params);
```

However, this works:

```js
let instance = new MyClass(params);
```

Why can't I use `window` in this case? Any other ideas?

Comment: You can only use `window` if it's a global variable. You must have defined the class in a local scope, not the global scope.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I'm in the constructor of another class.

Comment: A hacky way is to do `eval('var instance = new '+name+'()')`. The limitations look similar to an [older question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317114/determine-if-class-of-given-name-exists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only global variables are put into `window` automatically.

Create an object that maps from class names to classes:

```
const classMap = {
    "MyClass": MyClass,
    "MyClass2": MyClass2,
    ...
};
```

Then use `classMap[name](params)` rather than `window[name](params)`.